# WooCommerce product catalog, single product price range remove

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im search few codes to remove the price range from everywhere on my website, but only on single product worked,

still on product catalog and on home page as product slider :
https://prnt.sc/6hO9WYNwyi4j
https://prnt.sc/xDMbwtivwE6z

On single product i used that code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'move_variations_single_price', 1 );
function move_variations_single_price(){
  global $product, $post;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_variation_single_price', 10 );
  }
}

function replace_variation_single_price() {
  ?>
    <style>
      .woocommerce-variation-price {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var priceselector = '.product p.price';
        var originalprice = $(priceselector).html();

        $( document ).on('show_variation', function() {
          $(priceselector).html($('.single_variation .woocommerce-variation-price').html());
        });
        $( document ).on('hide_variation', function() {
          $(priceselector).html(originalprice);
        });
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

and worked , i tried to make something similar to shop catalog with this hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title but i cant, i want to fix that in all site not only on single product .

Comment: Your jQuery won't work, since the variation price isn't updated when the document is ready.

Comment: @HowardE Ok so in shop catalog what must do? is it sooo difficult? i searched more than hour on google and nothing worked